# Create Azure AD user by tenant and app ID

Tags: php, azure, azure-ad-graph-api

How I can create a user by Client secrets in Azure AD with PHP?

I need access token in below code to create a user. To have this token I need to login first. How I can create a user automatically without any login.

```
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
                  "accountEnabled": true,
                  "displayName": "Adele Vance",                  
                  "userPrincipalName": "adelev2@xxx.net",
                  "passwordProfile" : {
                    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
                    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
          }
        }',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
          ),
        ));
```

Comment: Hi,If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.) You can also accept your own answer :).

Comment: Hi @Carl. I used yours and up-voted it as a helpful answer. But the right answer is mine with the help of your provided link. To accept my answer it must pass two days after question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With special thanks to Carl which provide useful links I did it by using two below functions:

I receive a token by calling `getToken` function and use it in `getToken` to create a user without any previous login.

```
function getToken() {
       
    $curl = curl_init();
    
    $dir = env('OAUTH_DIR_ID');
    $clientId = env('OAUTH_APP_ID');
    $secretKey = env('OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD');
    
    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$dir/oauth2/v2.0/token",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "client_id=$clientId&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=$secretKey&grant_type=client_credentials",
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd; stsservicecookie=estsfd'
        ),
    ));
    
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    
    curl_close($curl);
    echo $response;
    
}

function addUser($accessToken)
{
    try {

        $curl = curl_init();
        
        curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
          CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users',
          CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
          CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
          CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
          CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
          CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
          CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
          CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
          CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>'{
                  "accountEnabled": true,
                  "displayName": "Adele Vance",                  
                  "userPrincipalName": "adelev2@yoed.net",
                  "passwordProfile" : {
                    "forceChangePasswordNextSignIn": true,
                    "password": "xWwvJ]6NMw+bWH-d"
          }
        }',
          CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "Authorization: Bearer $accessToken",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
          ),
        ));
        
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        
        curl_close($curl);
        
        var_dump($response); // Debug print
        exit();
        
        
    } catch (Error $ex) {
        $home = env('APP_URL');
        header("Location: $home/signin.php?err=" . $ex->getMessage());
        die();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to this [sample](https://github.com/pdaw/php-microsoft-graph-clientcred), which uses a daemon that does not require user login, and uses the [client credential flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow) to obtain an access token to call [MS graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create a user. You need to grant **User.ReadWrite.All** `application permissions` for the application.

[image]